# Take pictures and saving to SD card

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an app where you can take pictures and then display them on screen or upload a picture from your SD card and display on screen. Currently I am app to upload and display it on screen however when i select the option to take a photo I am able to take the photo and click save, however, the photo will not display on the screen nor will it save to the SD card. Please help!

```
public class UploadActivity extends Fragment {

    private Button bt_browse;
    private ImageView iv_photo;
    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private String uploadImagePath = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload,
                container, false);
        bt_browse = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        iv_photo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);


        bt_browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectImage();
            }
        });



        return rootView;

    }



    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bm;
                    BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), btmapOptions);

                    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                    iv_photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    uploadImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, getActivity());
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
                iv_photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                uploadImagePath = tempPath;

            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);

    }



    }
```

I have also added the following code to the Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: may be your onActivityResult() not called...start ur activty by getActivity().startActivityForResult(...)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

i was handled this Scenario with this methods as:

```
private void getImageFromCamera() {
    Log.i("GalaNotes", "From CAMERA Setting Capture TRUE");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getImageFromGallery() {
    Log.i("GalaNotes", "From Gallery Setting Capture TRUE");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
}
```

In the onActivityResult() method you can print the Uri or Path where it was stored as follows :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {

case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:


        try {

        log.i("Stored location of File",getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;



case PICK_FROM_FILE:
        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("PHOTO", "" + mImageCaptureUri.toString()); // UPLOAD FEEDS
        // RESPONSE
        // doCrop();
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, CropActivity.class);

        try {

            i.putExtra("imgSdcardPath", getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri));// mImageCaptureUri.toString());
            startActivityForResult(i, 212);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;

}}
```

If You have any Query then givefeedback on my Post.

Comment: Im sorry Ranjan, I am so new to this, where would i place the above code into mine? and would I need to remove any of my code?

Comment: you have to add above two methods in Your class  and change the code of onActivityResult() with this code. If there was have any issue please feedback me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [standart way](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) to get the photo from `onActivityResult`:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global Declaration 
Intent intent;
String imageFileName,videoFileName;
Uri uri;

private void clickPhotoFromCamera() {
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), imageFileName);
    uri = Uri.fromFile(imageStorageDir);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

private void captureVideoFromCamera() {
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    videoFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4";
    File videoStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), videoFileName);
    uri = Uri.fromFile(videoStorageDir);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

private void uploadMediaFromGallery() {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            imagePath = uri.getPath();
            // Do whatever you want with image path...
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            videoPath = uri.getPath();
            // Do whatever you want with Video path...
        } else {
            uri = data.getData();
            mediaPath = getPath(getApplicationContext(), uri);

        }
    }
}
```

// For get Image or video from path...

```
File mediaFile = new File(mediaPath);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (mediaFile.exists()) {

            if (isImage(mediaPath)) {

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int height = (myBitmap.getHeight() * 512 / myBitmap.getWidth());
                Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 512, height, true);
                int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    exif = new ExifInterface(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    rotate = 0;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                }

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                Bitmap rotateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scale, 0, 0, scale.getWidth(), scale.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                displayImage.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap);

            } else {

                bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mediaPath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                displayImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
public static boolean isImage(String str) {
        boolean temp = false;
        String[] arr = { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = str.endsWith(arr[i]);
            if (temp) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: With this example you can get image or video path. you can store that path for future use. and after that you can get image of video from path...